# Update preinstalled packages at ShareLaTeX

Tags: packages, sharelatex

I am using ShareLaTeX who have already preinstalled many packages.

Is it possible to manually update these packages to newer versions?

Comment: You can copy newer versions in the folder of your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, simple packages can be installed manually by finding the package file (ending in .sty) and saving it in the root directory. This will override any existing preinstalled package of the same name. The package file can usually be found on CTAN or similar.